# How to add the help text of a custom module in a separate template file in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, module, drupal-8

Following this documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/basic-structure, the help text can be added inside the hook_help() function in my_custom_module.module file when creating a custom module in Drupal 8.

I would like to put the help text in a separate template file and inside the hook_help() function I point to that template file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[hook_help()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21help%21help.api.php/function/hook_help/8.4.x) returns a renderable array, so you can use [custom theme and template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-from-custom-module) for this:

```
function help_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
    case 'your.custom.route':
      return ['#theme' => 'my_custom_theme'];
  }
}
```

Don't forget to use `t` function in your twig templates to support translation:

```
{{ "My string"|t }}
```